# Ruby continue in case

Tags: ruby

For example, I have the following code.

```
str = 'delay loss duplicate etc'
case str
    when /delay/ then
      puts 'delay'
    when /loss/ then
      puts 'loss'
end
```

I want give.

```
delay
loss
```

Is it possible in ruby not break all next conditions when the first coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure `case` is really what you want here.

```
str = 'delay loss duplicate etc'
regex = { /delay/ => 'delay', /loss/ => 'loss' }
regex.each { |r, s| puts s if str =~ r }
```

If you want another regex, just add a key/value pair to the hash.

Comment: This could, in Ruby 1.8, also result in the output "loss delay" (no line ends in comments), as the order in which the Hash returns the key-value pairs is not ordered.

Comment: True, but a) it's about time people moved on to 1.9 and b) you can always just add the appropriate `sort` before the `each`. :-)

Comment: Or you can use array of pairs instead of a hash, with no change to `each` below. :)

Comment: Sure, I just thought a hash has the added advantage of faster lookup if you also need it in another context. But then you could always just convert the array of arrays with the `Hash` method I guess.